# db2 between query for char columns

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a scenario where there is a table like below

Table Name:Employee

```
id EmpName(char 4) -always 4 chars only
1  ARUN
2  BALA
3  LOKI
```

I wanted a Db2 query which should get me the range of  employees who's name starting with A to D. Meaning employees whose name starts with A,B,C and D should be displayed

I have tried this query

```
select * from employee where empname between 'A000' and 'DZZZ'
```

Its not working properly

Comment: It doesn't? Specify names not returned as expected.

Comment: Also, are you using Postgresql or DB2?

Comment: i wanted on both the databases ,Db2 and postgres

Comment: Is there any other alternate way for achieving what i expect

Comment: Yes, several. But you want the same query to run on both DB2 and Postgresql, and the above query should work. Still, tell us one of the problem names.

Comment: No i don't want the query to be same,problem is on executing the above query i should get emp name ARUN and BALA but i am getting only the empname BALA

Comment: `where substr(empname, 1, 1) in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')`, or `where empname between 'AAAA' and 'DZZZ'`. The between query will perform better if the empname column is indexed.

Comment: Thank you ,this worked out for me where empname between 'AAAA' and 'DZZZ'

Comment: Which one, or both?

Comment: This one    select * from employee where empname between 'AAAA' and 'DZZZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to 'AAAA' as start value.

```
where empname between 'AAAA' and 'DZZZ'
```

Will perform much better, if empname is indexed.

ANSI SQL compliant and portable, should work fine on both DB2 and Postgresql.

**EDIT:**

If empnames shorter than 4 characters will be stored, you can change to:

```
where empname between 'A' and 'DZZZ'
```

(Will not miss employee 'A'.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following version:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where e.empname >= 'A' and
      e.empname < 'E'
```

This does exactly what you are asking for -- and making no assumptions about the second character.  In addition, it is index-safe, if you have an index on `empname` (although you are selecting so many rows that indexes probably are not relevant).

Comment: @LokeshkumarR Your query doesn't return what you expect because `0` has a high value is EBCDIC character set, `X'F0'`, so `A000` is higher than `ABCD` in EBCDIC. You might notice that `where between 'AAAA' and 'DZZZ'` will not select 'D000' for the same reason. Gordon Linoff's answer is better

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
select empname from employee where empname like 'A%' or 
empname like 'B%' or empname like 'C%' or 
empname like 'D%' 
order by empname
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this too**

```
select empname from employee where empname
REGEXP'^[ABCD]'
```